# Assigning CRS to Lat/Lon in R giving error: "Geographical CRS given to non-conformant data"

Tags: coordinate-system, r, error, latitude-longitude, proj

I have a list of suburbs in Queensland, Australia along with their lat/longs.

However, when I try to read in the file in R and assign a CRS, R is giving the following error message:

> Error in `proj4string<-`(`*tmp*`, value = ) : 
>    Geographical CRS given to non-conformant data: 153.53332931

Here are relevant lines of the code,

```
# Loading suburb list 
qs <- read.csv(file = '../data/Australian_Post_Codes_Lat_Lon.csv', 
               header = TRUE,
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

suburb <- qs %>% 
  filter(state == 'QLD') %>% 
  select(postcode,
         suburb,
         lat,
         lon) 

coordinates(suburb) <- c('lat', 'lon')
# Assigning proper Coordinate Reference System (CRS) to Lat/Long.
proj4string(suburb) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
```

I am using the csv file provided [here](http://www.corra.com.au/australian-postcode-location-data/)

Comment: Try `coordinates(suburb) <- c('lon', 'lat')` i think sp expects coordinates in xy not yx.

Answer (score 5):

It is what [TimSalabim commented](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257831/assigning-a-particular-crs-to-lat-lon-in-r-giving-error-geographical-crs-given#comment407242_257831), one need to pass `coordinates` function in xy order, hence, longitude and latitude.

I tested the .csv data and the following code works:

```
qs <- read.csv(file = '.../data/Australian_Post_Codes_Lat_Lon.csv', sep = ',')
suburb <- subset(qs, qs$state == 'QLD')

library(sp)
coordinates(suburb) <- c('lon', 'lat') #this is the line which answers the question.
proj4string(suburb) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
str(suburb)
```